# $\infty \leq \infty $ is right?

Tags: inequality, infinity

Friends, I am reading the book Convex Optimization by Boyd and I have encountered the inequality

$$f(\theta x+(1-\theta) y) \leq \theta f(x)+(1-\theta) f(y)$$

for $0 \leq \theta \leq 1$ and any $x$ and $y$.

When $x \notin \text{dom} f$, $f(x) = \infty$. So when both sides of the inequality are $\infty$, how are we able to compare?

In the text book, there is a sentence to explain; "Of course here we must interpret the inequality using extended arithmetic and ordering." 
What is "extended arithmetic and ordering"?

Comment: See [extended real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line).

Comment: "extend arithmetic and ordering" means convex property. If you think theta=1/2, then it is real arithmetic. And we could extend it by convex property of function.

Comment: It's simply not true that when $x\notin\mathrm {dom }\,f$ then $f(x)=\infty$. That is absolutely a false statement.

Comment: Previously asked at http://mathoverflow.net/q/255969/12357 where the OP was asked to post here.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, it extends function  f, if $x \in dom f$, $f = C$, otherwise, $f = \infty$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews No it is not. Actually, this *is* the convention within convex analysis.

Comment: @Herry, yeah, i know it's mean convex property. I lost some infomation when i want to description the problem simply. In the inequlity, the f has been extend to  $\overline{f} = f(x), if x \in dom f$. $\overline{f} = \infty, if x \notin dom f.$.  To the extended f,  the text book say it is also convex for **any x and y**. So the problem is that when $x,y \notin dom f$, the both side of the inequlity is \infty, is it right?

Comment: @Bye_World, in the part Algebraic properties of [extended real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line#Order_and_topological_properties), $1 \leq 1$ is right, so $1+\infty \leq 1+\infty$ and $ 1+\infty = \infty$, so $\infty \leq \infty$ is right.  Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @peasantspring Yes.  $\infty \le \infty$.  In fact, $a\le a$ for any $a\in \overline {\Bbb R}$.

Comment: @Bye_World  ok, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The extended reals is the real number set $ \mathbb{R} $ with the addition of two new symbols $ \infty $ and $ - \infty $. With axioms for these two symbols so it works in a consistent way.

Comment: what are the axioms?

Comment: @bye_world gave a link to them in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line